# symbolic integration of a definite integral, how to speed up

Tags: symbolic, performance-tuning

I am wondering what are the general tips & hints for speeding up symbolic integration. As far as I understand, it solely depends on the form a function is represented before it is processed by `Integrate`. So, `Simplify`, `ExpandAll`, `PowerExpand` *etc.* should be used. Are there any other strategies?

My monster function (it looks relatively simple, though) is:

```
f[r_]:=(A^(2) E^((2 r α)/(3)) α^(3) (A^(8/3) \
(-0.002396-0.001198 r α)+E^((8 r α)/(3)) α^(4) \
(0.00001755-(8.776*10^(-6)) r α)+A^(4/3) E^((4 r \
α)/(3)) α^(2) (-0.0002734+0.0004785 r α)))/(r \
(1.000 A^(4/3)+0.02853 E^((4 r α)/(3)) α^(2))^(4))
```

or (TeX)
$$    
\frac{A^2 \alpha ^3 e^{\frac{2 \alpha  r}{3}} \left(\alpha ^4 \
e^{\frac{8 \alpha  r}{3}} \left(0.00001755-\alpha  r \left(8.776
\times 10^{-6}\right)\right)+\alpha ^2 A^{4/3} (0.0004785 \alpha  \
r-0.0002734) e^{\frac{4 \alpha  r}{3}}+A^{8/3} (-0.001198 \alpha  \
r-0.002396)\right)}{r \left(0.02853 \alpha ^2 e^{\frac{4 \alpha  \
r}{3}}+1.000 A^{4/3}\right)^4}
$$

where $\alpha > 0$ and $A > 0$ are some parameters.

What I am trying to do:

`Integrate[f[r]*r^2*4*Pi,{r,O,Infinity}]`

Sure, I could have used `NIntegrate` for some specific $\alpha$ and $A$ (and belive me, I did it:), but now I am interested in the general result.

Seems like the situation is hopeless, because my laptop can not handle it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Analyze the integrand $f(r)r^2$:

```
{Expand[Numerator[#]], Denominator[#]} &  @ (Apart[f[r]][[#]] r^2 // FullSimplify) & /@ Range[3]
```

The result exhibits the integrand as a sum of six fractions whose numerators are in the form $\lambda \exp(2 r \alpha / 3) r^k$ for $k=1,2$ and whose common denominator is in the form $(1 + \mu \exp(4 r \alpha / 3))^2$ (after factoring out the constant $A^{8/3}$, which can be incorporated in $\lambda$).

This is still not easy to integrate symbolically.  However, from $\exp(\omega r) = 1 + \omega r + (\omega r)^2/2 + \cdots$ it follows (from the absolute convergence of the integrand when the real part of $\alpha$ is positive) that these integrals can be recovered from the MacLaurin series in $\omega$ for

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\exp(2 r \alpha / 3) \exp(\omega r)}{(1 + \mu \exp(4 r \alpha / 3))^2} dr.$$

The *Mathematica* expression for this integral is

```
u = Integrate[Exp[2 r α] Exp[ω r]/(1 + μ Exp[4 r α])^2, {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

Within a few seconds it returns a `ConditionalExpression` equal to

$$\frac{\frac{4 \alpha  \mu }{1+\mu }+\left(-\frac{1}{\mu }\right)^{\frac{1}{4} \left(-2+\frac{\omega }{\alpha }\right)} \mu  (2 \alpha -\omega ) \text{Beta}\left[-\frac{1}{\mu },\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\omega }{4 \alpha },0\right]}{16 \alpha ^2 \mu ^2}$$

provided $6 \text{Re}[\alpha ]>\text{Re}[\omega ]$ and $\text{Re}[\alpha ]>0$.

Since we only need this to converge for $\omega$ near $0$, this is tantamount to requiring $\text{Re}(\alpha) \gt 0$, which is clearly the case for otherwise the integral diverges.

Now compute the series coefficients of order $1$ and $2$:

```
SeriesCoefficient[u[[1]], {ω, 0, 1}]
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{1}{\mu }} \text{Beta}\left[-\frac{1}{\mu },\frac{3}{2},0\right]}{16 \alpha ^2}-\frac{\text{HypergeometricPFQ}\left[\left\{1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right\},\left\{\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2}\right\},-\frac{1}{\mu }\right]}{72 \alpha ^2 \mu ^2}$

That was only the first coefficient, but the second is found the same way (replacing the last `1` by `2`).  The second coefficient is messier, involving a linear combination of regularized generalized hypergeometric functions.  Don't forget to multiply it by $2!$.  Because so much manipulation and re-assembly is involved in obtaining the final answer (it's going to be a linear combination of $30$ such hypergeometric functions before any simplification), it would be a good idea to check your final result against numeric integrations in a range of representative cases.

---

#### Edit

It often helps to reduce the form of an integrand to the simplest possible--this gives *Mathematica* better chances to identify good simplifications.  In this case, the crux of the matter is to find integrals of the form

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\exp(x(1 + \tau))}{(1 + \exp(2 x + \sigma))^2}dx,$$

which can be obtained from the change of variable $x = 2 r \alpha / 3$ and letting $\mu = \exp(\sigma)$.  So we try

```
Integrate[Exp[x(1 + τ)] / (1 + Exp[2 x + σ])^2, {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

It's still a mess, but the series coefficients are a little simpler than before: they are linear combinations of up to five derivatives of a single *ordinary* (not regularized, not generalized) hypergeometric function.  That at least may be better known and easier to understand and perhaps easier for *Mathematica* to simplify when everything is recombined.

Comment: +1 When I tried this I got several `PolyLog`s from the indefinite integral. That made me think I won't learn anything from the analytic solution, as  opposed to just doing numerics. You definitely tried harder.

Comment: thnx a lot for yr help!!!

Comment: +1 this kind of answer certainly cannot be provided from one  who doesn't have enough knowledge and experience on general math as well as integration techniques. Well done!